# Add Hyperlink to a long column in Excel?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a long column to be added hyperlinks.
And the address start at 'https:www.***.com/'+ the account ID.
So each cell had customised address.
Currently I just created a new column use

```
=HYPERLINK('https:www.***.com/'&$A1,$A1)
```

and drag down to the column end.

I wanna know if I can do (definitely) it directly onto column A (Account ID column itself), keeping the ID's displayed and with hyperlinks as well.

The column is something like:

```
Account ID
101010101
101010102
101010103
101010104
101010105
101010106
...
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use VBA for this purpose. Here is VBA code to do this:

```
Sub LinkCreate()
Dim LastRow As Long, n As Integer, idName As String, addressLink As String
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For n = 2 To LastRow
    ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Select
    idName = ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).Value
    addressLink = "http://google.com/" & idName
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=addressLink, TextToDisplay:=idName
Next n
```

End Sub

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x_I7I1nAg1TjN3cGpHaDZpd2s) you can see my example file

Comment: Just don't forget to enable macros